# ¿Porqué no puedo utilizar versiones recientes de la librería jsPDF?

Tags: javascript, html, nodejs, pdf, jspdf

Mi aplicación (html, css, javascript puro, nodejs) y **requiere generar archivos PDF**.

Intento utilizar la **librería jsPDF**.
En el html coloco el script:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.3.4/jspdf.debug.js"></script>
```

(Observar que la versión es 1.3.4)

Cuando coloco  el script correspondiente a versiones superiores (las hay y muchas),
en mi archivo .js, la línea de código:

```
var doc = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'letter')
```

Arroja el error: **jsPDF is not defined**
Entiendo que no encuentra la librería.

A su vez, cuando intento utilizar algunas clases o métodos que figuran en la documentación
de jsPDF, no puedo hacerlo. Supongo que se debe a que estoy utilizando una versión antigua.

**Alguien me podría decir porqué no puedo utilizar versiones más recientes y cómo solucionarlo?**

Comment: ¿Dónde estás colocando el script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Según [la documentación](https://rawgit.com/MrRio/jsPDF/master/docs/index.html), por ejemplo, para version `2.5.1` de `jsPDF` si vas a utilizarlo desde:

- Nodejs

```js
const { jsPDF } = require("jspdf");

const doc = new jsPDF();
// ...
```

- El navegador:

```js
const { jsPDF } = window.jspdf;

const doc = new jsPDF();
// ...
```

**Demo desde el navegador:**

```js
const { jsPDF } = window.jspdf;

const doc = new jsPDF();
console.log(doc);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/2.5.1/jspdf.umd.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: muchas gracias por tu colaboración. Logré solucionar. Muy completa la respuesta.